# Expected score of a shot in archery

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is the question:

An archer fires at a circular target. Distances (in feet) from the target center are measured using Cartesian coordinates $(X,Y)$. Suppose each shot follows a random distribution with density 
$$f(X,Y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{−\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$$
There is a circular bull's eye at the center, and two surrounding rings, each of radius (or ring width) $0.5$ feet. The outermost ring scores $1$ point, the middle ring $4$ points, and the bull's eye, $5$ points. Find the expected score of one shot.

I tried to convert it to polar coordinates because there is absolutely no way that this is not a polar coordinate conversion problem, but I cannot figure out the limits. Also I am unsure as to compute it. Can anyone provide some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that the joint density is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)\right\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}.$$

Hence, we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and follow standard normal distributions. You can stop here are calculate the expected value of the score.

Or, you can further recognize that we only care about the length of the radius, and so we notice that
$R = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ follows a standard Rayleigh distribution.

---

We recognize that we are interested in the radius of the circles. Using first principles, we notice that we are interested in the event $R\in dr$. In words, this means we want the radius to fall in an infinitesimal annulus, with infinitesimal width $dr$, and area $2\pi rdr$. Since we were given that the height was $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}$, then
$$P(R\in dr) = 2\pi r\,dr\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\cdot\frac{1}{dr} = re^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}.$$

You can confirm that 
$$F_R(r) = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}.$$

So for the innermost circle, we have that the chance to hit it is
$$P(R<.5) = F_R(.5) = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{8}}.$$

Comment: My confusion here is how I would go about doing this? The radius is .5 but there are 3 rings so would I do 0 to 1.5? Of the joint density?

Comment: If you want to use the joint density then for the innermost ring, I believe you want $P(|X|<.5,|Y|<.5) = P(|X|<.5)P(|Y|<.5) = (\int_{-.5}^{.5}f_X(x)\,dx)^2.$

Comment: Then would I continue on this path, and do from -1 to 1 and then -1.5 to 1.5 or would I just cube this answer? also how would I factor in my actual scoring system into this

Comment: Those bounds will give you the probability of being in each particular circle, but that does not give you the probability of getting a particular score. in other words, it does not give the probability of hitting each particular ring. If $Z$ is the value of the score, the $E[Z] = \sum_z zP(Z = z).$

Comment: I'm at a complete loss here, the marginal density of x is the first half of the marginal densities of x and y combined right? From there I integrate using -.5 and .5 and then integrated in each circle. How do I apply these integrations to the score using that formula. For -.5 to .5 I got .1466314963. For -1 to 1 I got .4660649427. Finally, for -1.5 to 1.5 I got .7506240035.

Comment: I'm going to assume those values are correct. But for example, the last one give the chance of hitting the largest circle. To get the chance that you hit the outermost ring, you subtract the chance of hitting the smaller circle. This gives the chance of scoring 1 point since you hit the outermost ring.

Comment: Would i then just add all of these expected values? and also would i do 1 - all of these values first to get the right probability?

Comment: @probablyme (|X|<.5,|Y|<.5) does not describe a ring if I am not mistaken...

Comment: @user190080 Haha, you're right! I must've had something else on my mind. I just wanted to use a Rayleigh. I didn't want to think very much. Thanks!!

Comment: @AndreCocagne As user190080 points out, I made a mistake. The thing I wrote describes a box, not a circle. You want to do $P(X^2+Y^2<.5)$ for the innermost ring. Follow the same procedure to get the chance of hitting each ring. Yes, you add up $\sum_z zP(Z = z)$ to get the expected score. I have no idea what you are talking about doing $1-$.

Comment: @probablyme how would that change my integral? would it be both marginal densities added and squared now?

Comment: @AndreCocagne It changes is drastically. It would be much easier if you derived the distribution of $R = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$, or if you covered, notice that this follows a Rayleigh distribution. To find the cdf of $R$, compute $P(R<r) = P(X^2+Y^2<r^2) = \int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy\,dx.$ Or you can use first principles to find $P(R\in\,dr).$

Comment: @AndreCocagne I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm so can you explain to me why its 1/dr? Also, I solved the rest and it worked... I really do appreciate the help. This stuff just flies right over my head, I like differential equations much much more xD For reference I got 1.973258651 as my final answer.

Comment: @AndreCocagne Loosely speaking, $f_X(x) = P(X\in dx) \,dx$. I got $1.973259$ using the thing I derived. In general, this stuff is really interesting if you approach it correctly. If not or if you are assigning sucky problems, then it just becomes tedious busy work. That's never fun.

Comment: @probablyme I think a big issue is my professor prefers to go over proofs of things that he doesn't do beforehand so we sit in class doing one proof, but to not get behind he tells us to "read the book" to solve the homework. It has made for a rather tough Probability and Stats class where I had the highest grade on the previous exam with a C+... It's turned me off from probability theory quite well. But again, I do appreciate the help, and on the bright side my class is almost done for the semester!

Comment: @AndreCocagne That's unfortunate. But you are more than welcome to ask questions here. I'll try to do a better job next time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Use the PDF of the distance from the center $d = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.